# Python list of variables inside a class

Tags: python, python-2.7

this is my first question, and combined with my being fairly noob feel free to tell me if there is a completely different way I should be going about this!

Anyways, I am building a program that involves coloring a map with the four color theorem in Python 2.7, attempting to use certain colors as much as possible, and I ran into a problem when running something like this code:

In one module:

```
class state:
    a = 0
    b = 0
    variable_list = [a,b]
```

Then I import that module into my main program:

```
from State import state  //State(uppercase "s") is the .py file with the state class in it

instance = state()

instance.a = 1

print instance.variable_list[0]
```

...and the program prints 0, despite changing it in the main program.  Any thoughts on how to update instance.variable_list with the change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at your class code.

```
class state:
    a = 0
    b = 0
    variable_list = [a,b]
```

a becomes 0, b becomes 0. Therefore, the list "variable_list" becomes [0, 0].
You then proceeded to change a using this code:

```
instance.a = 1
```

Which worked. The objects instance a variable is indeed 1. However, variable_list is still [0, 0]! The list remained it's original value because the list itself wasn't changed. The code you ran to make the list is only ran once. To solve this, you can make a function to update variable_list based on the *current* values of a and b (not the original values). For instance you can make a function to update the variable list like so:

```
def updateVariableList(self):
    variable_list = [self.a, self.b]
```

when you call that function using instance.updateVariableList(), it will update the values of the list based on the current values of a and b. Now print instance.variable_list[0] will show the updated values.

Answer (score 2):

You have to think of Python variables in terms of pointers. Your question really boils down to the following:

```
>>> a = 42
>>> l = [a]
>>> a = 0
>>> print l[0]  # shouldn't this print 0?
42
```

The answer is no, because re-assigning `a` has nothing to do with the list `l`. The list contains pointers to certain objects in memory. `l[0]` happens to be pointing to the same object as `a` (the int `42`). When we reassign `a`, we simply have it "point" to a new object in memory (the int `0`). This has no bearing on the list `l`.

It looks like this:

```
a = 42
l = [a]

                      +----+
            a  -----> | 42 | <------ l[0]
                      +----+

a = 0

                      +----+
            l[0] ---> | 42 |
                      +----+

                      +---+
            a ------> | 0 |
                      +---+
```

Notice that `l[0]` has not changed.

Comment: thanks arshajii, this was very helpful! (and the pseudo-graphics with text was a nice touch)

Answer (score 2):

I'll cut to what I think you *want* to be doing.

```
class State(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0
        self.b = 0
    @property
    def variable_list(self):
        return self.a, self.b
```

and usage:

```
state = State()

state.a = 1

state.variable_list
Out[23]: (1, 0)
```

Notable changes from your code:

- You're grabbing an instance of `State`, so make the attributes *instance* attributes, not class attributes.  I doubt you want every instance of `State` to share the same attributes.
- `@property` decorator makes it so you can access `variable_list` just like it's a regular attribute, but you can customize the behavior of what it returns - in this case, a couple of instance attributes.
- Inherit from `object` to get a ["new-style"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python) class.  Trust me on this, there is essentially no reason to be using an old-style class nowadays.
- Naming conventions.  Classes start with upper case letters.

Answer (score 0):

When you update the variable `a` it does not update that instance but simply assigns it a different int with a completely different pointer. Therefore, this change does not reflect that change in the list as you expected it would.

You could either add a `update` method in your list that does:

```
def update():
    variable_list = [a,b]
```

and call it every time you update your variables.

Or, you could simply use a dictionary and do away with individual variables:

```
class state:
    variables = {'a': 0, 'b': 1}

x = state()
print x.variables['a']

x.variables['a'] = 1
print x.variables['a']

[OUTPUT]
0
1
```

Comment: This answer is somewhat misleading. You're not creating a copy (just try printing the `id()` of `a` and of `variable_list[0]`); rather, you're just redirecting the `instance.a` pointer to point elsewhere, which has nothing to do with `variable_list`.

Comment: @arshajii, I have updated my answer. If you feel it is still somewhat inadequate, please feel free to edit it. Thank you very much.

Comment: The edit is a step in the right direction, but the statement *"This is because ints are immutable objects"* is still not accurate; this has nothing to do with the immutability of ints -- try it with lists, for example.